# Regex hashtag & html entity mixup

Tags: php, regex

I have the regex expression `#(\w+)` to catch a hashtag like **#wine** in a string and it also happens to pickup on html entities like &**#039**;. I'd need it to avoid these by looking for the ampersand. How can I validate this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using a negative [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind) assertion if your language's regex engine supports them:

```
(?<!&)#(\w+)
```

Failing that, this would do the trick (although somewhat less elegantly):

```
(?:^|[^&])#(\w+)
```

Comment: The second regex would match `t#wine` which might not be wanted.

Comment: Sure. I don't know exactly what the OP has in mind. Perhaps, for example, `foo bar baz (#wine)` *should* match. It's easy to tweak the second regular expression as needed.

Comment: lang is php, this works thanks, I always have trouble with the negative look behind thanks for the doc.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a regex like this `(?:^|\s)(#\w+)` and pick the first captured group as the match.

Comment: This is no good. Word boundaries occur when a word character follows a nonword character (of vice versa). Since "#" is a nonword character, the preceding character would need to be a word character, which is almost certainly not what the OP has in mind. Here's a quick test case you can run in your browser's console: `/\b#\w+\b/.test('#foo #bar #baz')` (spoiler: it returns `false`).

Comment: @davidchambers thanks for pointing out. fixed the regex. I was just trying something simple without look-behind and erred :)